# Access to the server with all ports closed

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, remote-access

I received an email that ddos attacks are being made from my server using port 53. well as I'm not an expert on these things. I thought as I have firewall rules for those ports I need, I should close all other ports. So I created a rule closing all ports (0-65535). The moment I clicked the button obliviously my session ended as RDP port was closed too.

Now I have lost the connection to the server and data center  is not helping they told me to connect to the server using vnc viewer using the port 47773, and I tell them that this port is also closed and they should connect to the server locally and remove the rule. however they are not acception that.

Is there anything I can do about it? any way that I can connect to the server?

I have the all the passwords, The Adminstrator password, the one that data center suggest that I should use to connect and ...

Comment: DId you try to connect to port 47773 via VNC as they advised you? Maybe there is some remote management console on there not affected by your mistake.

Comment: Do you have KVM access to the server (via IPMI or the equivalent for the hardware or virtualization environment you're using)? If not, your data centre probably has some sort of "remote hands" service where they will perform some specified maintenance task for you, though usually at a fairly steep price.

Comment: well I did  but the vnc viewer gives me an error: Timed out waiting for a response from the host computer

Comment: @n.st the access that data center asks me to use is the KVM access. I have the username and password for it but vnc viewer using the port 47773 never reaches the point to ask me the username and password and it times out. Is there a setting or anything I should do before that?

Comment: You need to work this out with your data center.

Comment: Are you sure they mean port 47773 on your server's IP? If it's an external KVM, it might have a different IP.

Comment: well the link they have sent me, is my own server ip.

Comment: They might have provided you some sort of control panel where you can have console access to your VM (via KVM).You can access your VM from there and disable the firewall. Alternatively, if you have availed backup of your VM then you can restore whole VM from the previous working image.